# I set up an time interval call to fetch REST API with even id. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Earlier I tried to write a code to request only even ID posts from [rest api](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/), but it started to returned in random order. So I added a `setTimeout` in the `returneEven()` to reduce the crowdedness of requests (idrk what happened, if anyone can clarify what happened). So, `setTimeout` seem to solved the case. I wonder If this is the best practice to receive a curated data. I thought about calling  all the post and do  the filtering on client side. but What if that's just too big to manage? And requesting every 100ms repeitively, am I taxing the server too much and am I slowing down clientside too much?

Currently, it's  appending in 100ms. This means if I had 100 of even posts to request for, it would take at least 5 seconds to load. I don't think I'm doing this right. Is there some way for server to sort the data for us?

I've tried 10ms, and it would jumble up.

The code below, appends posts of all even posts 2 - 18

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>posts</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  
</div>
  <button id="clickme"> click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function loadDoc(str) {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.querySelector("#container").append(this.responseText);
  }
  };
  xhttp.open('GET', "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + str, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

let i = 0;
let run = document.querySelector('#clickme');
run.addEventListener('click', returnEven );


function returnEven() {
    if (i%2 == 0 && i != 20) {
    loadDoc(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(() => returnEven(), 100);
  } else if (i == 20) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i++;
    returnEven()
  }
}
```

[jfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/8svt3jew/)

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this... If the API doesn't have a way to request only even numbered posts, then just request all posts and filter out the odd numbered ones on the client side when they're received. If you absolutely must do it this way for some reason, then make the call for the next post in the callback after receiving the first post to guarantee order. Or don't append them right away: push them to an array and, after the last request finishes, sort the array before appending the elements to the DOM.

Comment: One more point: the server could definitely sort the data for you if it supported a way to request only even numbered posts; then you could specify a range and it would return the even numbered posts in order. But the API you're using doesn't support that, so there's nothing you can do like that (the server doesn't know that your many requests are related to each other).